# How can I ping, tracepath behind the proxy without using vpn?

Tags: proxy, ping

I am using a network that requires HTTP Proxy.Internet is working fine.

```
$ wget google.com
--2017-10-18 21:52:48--  http://google.com/
Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=tX_nWcnwLq6A8Qenx4zICw [following]
--2017-10-18 21:52:48--  http://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=tX_nWcnwLq6A8Qenx4zICw
Reusing existing connection to xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                          [ <=>                                                 ]  14.20K  --.-KB/s    in 0.06s   

2017-10-18 21:52:48 (241 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [14537]
```

But I am not able to ping.

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.197.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
14 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 13315ms
```

Tracepath

```
$ tracepath google.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                                         pmtu 1500
 1:  192.168.xx.x                                         0.621ms 
 1:  192.168.xx.x                                          0.593ms 
 2:  no reply
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  no reply
 .
 .
```

If I use VPN then everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

It's because a proxy and a VPN are different services.

A VPN creates a virtual network card, allowing you to use TCP, UDP, ICMP, SSH, FTP, and any other protocol. It gets its own IP address and have its own routing.

On the other hand, a proxy server acts as a relay. There's a specific proxy protocol to handle HTTP - it's called HTTP proxy for this reason. And there's a SOCKS proxy that can proxy any service that is TCP/IP based (HTTP/HTTPS, SSH, FTP...).

Ping and traceroute are services using ICMP protocol, so your proxy will not be able to tunnel them.